# How I can configure access to domain.com/api in traefik?

Tags: traefik, traefik-ingress

I need to configure traefik and get access to /api **https://example.com/api** . How I can do that? I have access only to /dashboard.
I tired, help pls
I tryed

```
services:
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.4"
    container_name: "traefik"
    command:
      - "--api=true"
      - "--api.dashboard=true"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.to=websecure"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.httpchallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint=web"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.email=example@gmail.com"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - traefik_default
    volumes:
      - "letsencrypt:/letsencrypt"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
    labels:
    #  - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.rule=Host(`example.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.service=api@internal"
    #  - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=websecure"
    #  - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.tls.certresolver=myresolver"
    #  - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.service=api@internal"
volumes:
  letsencrypt:
networks:
  traefik_default:
    external: true
```

I tryed this:
labels:

- "traefik.http.routers.api.rule=PathPrefix(`/api`) || PathPrefix(`/dashboard`)"
- "traefik.http.routers.api.service=api@internal"
- "traefik.http.routers.api.middlewares=auth"
- "traefik.http.middlewares.auth.basicauth.users=test:$$apr1$$H6uskkkW$$IgXLP6ewTrSuBkTrqE8wj/,test2:$$apr1$$d9hr9HBB$$4HxwgUir3HP4EsggP/QNo0"

but it didnt help me

Comment: PathPrefix+Host rules should work, label should be on the container serving that address -- your sample only shows Traefik

Comment: okay. how to configure for access to /api?  @SYN